# Getting "HRESULT: 0x800A01A8" error while hiding rows using vsto on vs2005

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am attempting to hide some rows in an excel sheet using C#.

but the line

```
deleteRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
```

is giving errors.

The entire code of selecting the range and hiding the rows is given below

```
string rowCnt = Convert.ToString(excelExportData.Tables["AllVersionDts"].Rows.Count + 8);
string startCell = "A" + rowCnt;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range deleteRange = ws.get_Range(startCell+":A65536",Missing.Value);
deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);

deleteRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
```

Please look into this code and say where am I going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Delete" somehow changed your range. Redefine the range right before hidden:

```
deleteRange = ws.get_Range(startCell+":A65536",Missing.Value);
deleteRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
```

Comment: @Jagannath Swain: You can go ahead and accept PerlDev's answer by clicking the hollow check-mark next to this answer.